# Access several controls with a for in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I Got this form with several Labels inside a GroupBox, all with the same name plus a number (similar to the default Label1, Label2, LabelN)

I'm changing the look and content of this labels with a sub(), but I can't figure out how to refer to each label without write the complete name it's possible to do something like:

```
To All Labels inside Group Box 
Sub(LabelN)
```

Currently I'm creating an Array of labels and assigning the names when the form loads, something like:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LabelMatrix(0) = Label1
        LabelMatrix(1) = Label2
        LabelMatrix(2) = Label3
        LabelMatrix(3) = Label4
....
    End Sub
```

But I suppose there must be a better (and smarter) way to do this.

I wanted to do it in a way that I get the total of the Labels objects in the Groups box but my efforts were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy, no arrays required:

```
For Each lbl As Label In MyGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
    ' ... do something with "lbl"
Next lbl
```

Comment: Just depends on what you're doing I suppose.  The order of the controls returned (if that matters for your scenario) may not be what you expect if the controls were added/removed, or their names were changed at some point in the design of the form.  If the controls you want to target are in multiple containers then the Controls.Find() becomes really handy.  =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to build the control names, and Controls.Find() to get a reference to the desired control.  Something like:

```
    Dim lbl As Label
    Dim matches() As Control
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        matches = Me.Controls.Find("Label" & i, True)
        If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is Label Then
            lbl = DirectCast(matches(0), Label)
            ' ... do something with "lbl" ...
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Great solution, I suppose that before that I assign the values to matches would be better to ReDim it with GetLength, don't?

Comment: No, matches() will be created and populated automatically for you by Controls.Find().  It's technically possible for multiple controls to have the same name which is why an array is returned.  The IDE prevents name collisions at design-time, but it can't enforce that rule for run-time created controls.  If the number of controls is static, then you can use code like I gave above to build a List **once** when the program first starts.