# Adding images into next available picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a deck builder project through a card database and so far when I click a row (using datagridview), the value contained in the "image_url" column is printed into an invisible textbox, which is then used to download that image and show it in a picturebox.

Now that all works fine, but decks go up to 60 cards so I'm going to use 60 pictureboxes to print the user's selected cards. What I'm been trying to do is set up like a picturecount and when they select a column the number is increased by one like this:

```
picturebox(picturecount) = textbox4.text
```

but I've run into too many errors. Would you know a way to display the user's selected card in the next available picturebox? For example if they select "Dark Magician" three times, then the image of the "Dark Magician" is printed in the first available three pictureboxes

VB.NET:

```vb
Private Async Sub PictureLoader()
    Dim imageURL As String

    If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
        imageURL = dataSet.Tables("YGO cards").Rows(row_count).Item(7)
    Else
        imageURL = TextBox4.Text
    End If

    Dim client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient()
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(New Uri(imageURL)))

    Using image As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
        PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(image.Clone(), Image)
    End Using

    ms.Dispose()
    client.Dispose()
End Sub
```

and this is the event when a column is selected in the datagrid!

```
Dim index As Integer
        index = e.RowIndex
        Dim selectedrow As DataGridViewRow
        selectedrow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)
' selectedrow.Cells(1) is the image_Url column        
TextBox4.Text = selectedrow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()

        If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
            ' imageURL = dataSet.Tables("YGO cards").Rows(row_count).Item(7)
        Else
            PictureLoader()
        End If
```

Comment: I like the dynamic approach by David below.  If, however, you want to stick with a static number of controls, then you can get a reference to each picturebox using `Controls.Find()`.  See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19840290/2330053) for one example.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Idle_Mind and previous answer I'll see which one I prefer!

Answer (score 1):

Ignore for a moment the specifics of your particular problem and break this down into a generic statement. What you're saying is that you have a collection and that the size of the collection can grow or shrink based on user input. This is an ideal case for a [List(Of T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) where you declare the List by specifying the data type of the items it will hold and then add items as needed. Because you are storing the URL of the card, you would create a new List(Of String):

```
Dim cards As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

Now whenever you needed to add URLs to your list you would call the Add method if it is a single URL or AddRange if it is multiple URLs:

```
cards.Add(TextBox1.Text)
'Or
cards.AddRange({TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text})
```

As far as displaying the image in the PictureBox, there's really no need to create a MemoryStream and clone an Image considering that the PictureBox class has the [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.load) and [LoadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync) (which it looks like you want asynchronous capabilities) methods. But if you wanted to create a PictureBox for every item in your collection, you will need to iterate through the collection, create a new PictureBox, call the Load or Load Async method on the currently iterated URL, and then add it to the Form (or a container in general). This can be done using a traditional For/Each loop:

```
'Create a placeholder variable
Dim cardPictureBox As PictureBox

'Loop through every selected card URL
For Each url As String In Cards
    'Create a new PictureBox
    cardPictureBox = New PictureBox() With {
        .Size = New Size(100, 100)
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        .WaitOnLoad = False
    }
    'Add the PictureBox to the Form
    Me.Controls.Add(cardPictureBox)

    'Load the image asynchronously
    cardPictureBox.LoadAsync(url)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks heaps David it works with less code then mine!!!!!! Now I'll just change the cardpicturebox code so that each time it's created the position moves to the right by 5!

Comment: One thing I would suggest is adding the controls to a `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`. In that case, there's no need for you to set the `Location` as the container will handle that for you.